# DateTime - Symfony FormBuilder passing value

Tags: php, datetime, formbuilder

I am geting a specific DateTime value from database that I want to pass as optional value in form rendering (doesnt't work) but also a option that can be changed (that option is working).

I am getting the date but I am having trouble passing it trough my form builder.

My (part of) code:

```
    $lastDate = $transactions[count($accounts) - 1]->getDate();
    $theDate = $lastDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('issuingDate', DateType::class, array(
                'data'  => $theDate,
                'label' => false,
                'attr'  => array(
                    'date' => (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d  H:i:s'),
                )))
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save', 'attr' => [
                'class' => 'btn btn-bg btn-primary'
            ]))
            ->getForm();
```

Everything else seems to be working fine.

Comment: How is it not working exactly? what's the expected and actual behaviour? 
Do you need to pass the 'attr' array here?

Comment: Yes, when I pass array, it sets a DateTime widget in my twig view.  But I want to datetime value that I get as default when renedring tamplate. @matiit

Comment: I posted my guess as a response, it's guess as I am not 100% sure I follow exactly what you need, hope that helps though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lastDate = $transactions[count($accounts) - 1]->getDate();


$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('issuingDate', DateType::class, array(
            'data'  => $lastDate,
            'data_class' => \DateTime::class,
            'label' => false,
            ))
        ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save', 'attr' => [
            'class' => 'btn btn-bg btn-primary'
        ]))
        ->getForm();
```

This should be enough to display a form with the date prefilled with $lastDate object's value.